# Immersion between manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I am currently reading various papers in the field of differential geometry and one thing has caught my attention: the authors always consider a smooth manifold $M$ and an immersion $x:M\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and then they identify $M$ with its image $\Sigma:=x(M)$  and call this an immersed submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. Going back to my lecture notes, the usual way is to parameterize $\Sigma$ for $p\in\Sigma$ by $\kappa:U\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}\longrightarrow V\subset\Sigma$, $U,V$ open. Now, choose a chart $(y,\tilde{U})$ around $x^{-1}(p)$ on $M$.

Is there a natural way to connect or identify the coordinates on $M$ induced by $y$ with those on $\Sigma$ chosen from $\kappa$? My cunfusion regarding this question arises from the fact that I wonder why we consider $\Sigma$ being the image $x(M)$, instead of simply saying that we have $\Sigma\subset\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. Whats the benefit from this "identification" of $\Sigma$ with $M$?

Answer (score 1):

> My confusion regarding this question arises from the fact that I wonder why we consider $\Sigma$ being the image $()$, instead of simply saying that we have $\Sigma\subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. Whats the benefit from this "identification" of $\Sigma$ with $M$?

Well, without an immersion $x:M\xrightarrow{} \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, the subset $\Sigma$ itself is not a manifold. As an example, consider the figure eight on the plane, which is not a manifold because at the center (double) point it isn't locally diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$. But if you see it as an immersion of $S^1$, you can talk about the charts, just like the $\kappa$ you mentioned. Without the information that it is immersed, the image $\Sigma$ is necessarily a submanifold, simply because it has 'self-intersections'. Also, when you have the immersion in hand, it gives you an identification between the tangent spaces of $M$ and subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. For example in the figure eight, the immersion of $S^1$ will induce two such subspaces at the center point.

> Is there a natural way to connect or identify the coordinates on $M$ induced by $y$ with those on $\Sigma$ chosen from $\kappa$? ... Now, choose a chart $(,\tilde{U})$ around $x^{-1}(p)$ on $M$.

Like I said, you actually can't choose charts $\kappa$ unless you consider $\Sigma$ as an immersed submanifold. Also, $x^{-1}(p)$ is not necessarily a single point, so you can't really choose a chart around it. A useful thing would be to consider $M$ as an abstract manifold whenever immersions are involved.

Comment: thanks. Let me be a bit more precise: that $\Sigma$ as a subset is not a submanifold in general is clear. I meant the following: when parameterizing the figure 8, the domain of the immersion „contains“ what we call the coordinates. In my question, the domain of the immersion $x$ is M, which is a manifold and therefore itself needs coordinates. This confuses me.

Comment: @GiulianoCantina What do you mean the domain of the immersion 'contains' coordinates? $M$ as an abstract manifold doesn't have 'coordinates'. Its manifold structure is given together with an atlas, which consists of charts and diffeomorphisms. I am assuming by 'coordinate' you mean these local charts? Either way, this doesn't change the fact that you can't choose $\kappa$ because $\Sigma$ is not a submanifold. What exactly confuses you about those 'coordinates'?

Comment: When defining  $f:\mathbb{S}^{1}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^{2}$ as the immersion of figure 8, in order to write down $f$ explicitly, we have to write $f(\kappa (\theta))=…$, where $\kappa$ is the parameterization of the unit sphere, $\theta\in (0,2\pi)$. Now, we can as well just parameterize figure 8 „directly“ without mentioning it as the image of the sphere. So what’s the point of viewing it this way?

Comment: @GiulianoCantina Well, when you say you parameterize $S^1$, you are actually choosing local charts on it. By definition, a manifold is a topological space equipped with an atlas, you are assuming more than that. Consider $\mathbb{R}P^n$ as the quotient of $S^n$. You have the quotient topology and $\mathbb{R}P^n$ is locally diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$, but there is no parameterization per se. In a first course in differential geometry, what we call a 'parameterization' is actually an atlas. Moreover in that case, we consider (for example a surface) as already embedded into Euclidean space.

Comment: Once again, because you know what figure eight actually comes from $S^1$ and you are actually using that correspondence in your parameterization. What you are doing is not different from what you think you are avoiding. Parameterizing figure eight by $(0,2\pi)$ is literally looking at it as the image of an immersed $S^1$. If I give you a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with a bunch of self intersections, there is no canonical way to see that it is indeed an immersed submanifold. Plus, different immersed submanifolds might have the same image. You can create figure eight using one $S^1$ or two $S^1$s.

Answer (score 0):

By Local immersion theorem, there is a co-ordinate/charts $\psi, \phi$ by which $x : M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is an inclusion i.e., $\psi x \phi^{-1} \left(x_1,...,x_{\dim(M)} \right) = \left(x_1,...,x_{\dim(M)},0,...,0 \right)$. Here $\psi: V \subseteq x(M) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{\dim(M)} \times 0^{n+1-\dim(M)}$. So you can think that $\kappa = \psi^{-1}$ (after removing $0^{n+1-\dim(M)}$).